# Mock provider in Angular2

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I want to unit test my Angular2 component. As I have other dependencies registered I want to mock some of them, especially which makes server requests.

I have bootsrapped my site using Angular CLI so have auto-generated test wrappers when new component is creating

So my `beforeEach` is:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockHttpService.get = jasmine.createSpy('mockHttpService.get').and.callFake(() => {return { subscribe: () => {} }});

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],

      //service substitution
      providers: [{provide: Http, useValue: mockHttpService}, ...],
      imports: [HttpModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

I've created mock for HTTP service:

```
let mockHttpService = {get: () => {return { subscribe: () => {} }}};
```

All I need - it's to check if request was initiated on OnInit stage. So I have very simple test:

```
  it('should load dictionary data', () => {
    spyOn(mockHttpService, 'get');

    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(mockHttpService.get).toHaveBeenCalled(); //NEVER CALLED
  });
```

I've cleared all my component logic and have single line in my OnInit handler:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(result => this.data = result.json());
  }
```

Why my test says that `mockHttpService.get` never called?

Comment: Why not `mockHttpService = jasmine.createSpyObj('MockHttpService', ['get'])`? Also note you can test the functionality more effectively using the `MockBackend` Angular provides: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html

Comment: I checked both. I like this syntax better.

Comment: You *prefer* `{get: () => {return { subscribe: () => {} }}}`? Fair enough. But I'd use `mockHttpService.get.and.returnValue(Observable.of(...))`.

Comment: It not important as I need to stop on `mockHttpService.get` was called only

Comment: But then you're not testing it does the right thing with the returned value. How do you check that `this.data` is being assigned correctly?

Comment: I just simplified my code to have only valuable data. I have other tests to check data and my mock service looks similar to your proposal: `mockHttpService.get = jasmine.createSpy('mockHttpService.get').and.callFake(() => {
      return {
        subscribe: (callback: Function) => {
          callback.call(component, { json: () => mockHttpServiceData});
        }
      }
    });`

Comment: Oof, that's a bit of a mess. You should really look at the `MockBackend`; they provided it for a reason.

Comment: I've changed mock - it looks better, but still no luck :( `mockHttpService.get = jasmine.createSpy('mockHttpService.get').and.callFake(() => Observable.of({json: () => mockHttpServiceData}));`

Comment: I agree with @jonrsharpe. [MockBackend](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html) is the way to go.