# Angular 2 Observable Service Karma Jasmine Unit Test not working

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I am a newbie to Angular 2 and Karma + Jasmine unit tests.  I cannot figure out what semantic error I have made in order to make this unit test use the mocked response. In the console, when "expect(items[0].itemId).toBe(2);" is run, it says items[0].itemId is undefined.

Would someone be able to help me out or point me in the right direction? Please let me know if you need any additional information.  Thanks!

item.ts

```
export class Item {
     itemId: number;
     itemName: string;
     itemDescription: string;
}
```

item.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
    import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { Item } from './item';
@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    constructor(
    private http: Http)
    {

    }

    getItems(listOptions: Object): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.http.post('/listItems', listOptions, {headers:this.headers})
       .map(response => response.json() as Item[])
  }
}
```

item.service.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, fakeAsync, inject, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { Http, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ItemService } from './item.service';
import { Item } from './item';


describe('ItemService', () => {
  let mockResponse, matchingItem, connection;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ItemService,
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (backend, defaultOptions) => new Http(backend, defaultOptions),
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        },
        // { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }        
      ]
    });

    const items = [
      {
        "itemId":2,
        "itemName":"test item1",
        "itemDescription":"hello hello"        
      },
      {
        "itemId":1,
        "itemName":"name2124111121",
        "itemDescription":"description212412112"        
      }
    ];
    mockResponse = new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: {data: items}, status: 200}));
  });

  describe('getItems', () => {

    //Subscribing to the connection and storing it for later
    it('should return all the items',inject([ItemService, MockBackend], (service: ItemService, backend: MockBackend) => {

        backend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
          connection.mockRespond(mockResponse);
        });
        service.getItems({isActive: true, sortColumn: "lastModifiedDateUtc", sortOrder: "desc"})
        .subscribe((items: Item[]) => {
          expect(items.length).toBe(2);
        });
      }));
    });
  });
```

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/m7In2eVh6oXu8VNYFf9l?p=preview
(There are some errors with the Plunkr I need help with as well but the main files are there)

Comment: `response.json()` isn't the array of items, `response.json().data` is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks! I get an error that says `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Item[]'`

Comment: Yes, because you've used the wrong type for the argument.

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you tell me what type I should use?

Comment: The one that reflects *the actual object you're sending*? In this case, something that has a field named `data` which contains the item array. If that's different than the actual payload, fix your test to reflect the real structure.

Comment: took me a little while to understand your solution but realized after talking to a co-worker this is where my error was: `mockResponse = new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: {data: items}, status: 200}));` should be `mockResponse = new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: items, status: 200}));` Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mockResponse body did not match the actual response body, that is why I was getting the error.

`mockResponse = new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: {data: items}, status: 200}));` should be `mockResponse = new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: items, status: 200}));`